# Firefox awesomebar database

Tags: database, firefox

I want to implement awesomebar like search functionality in my java application.
I like the way it searches the text patterns `in between` the words. Does it uses lucene library or performs like query on the database.

Which database do i choose for such type of pattern searching ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of Firefox is backed up by [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) databases, including bookmarks and search history which are stored in [`places.sqlite`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.sqlite). Although I don't have the [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/download_mozilla_source_code) to check (which you could just download and have a look at how they do it), I suspect that since it's SQLite then there is probably something along the lines of a [`LIKE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) in there to do the sub-string matching.